# Find latest available RVM version number

Tags: ruby, rvm

I can't seem to find an easy way to identify the *latest* release of RVM from command line or rvm.beginrescueend.com!?!

I currently type `rvm get latest` every few days or so to update RVM. If version is same, RVM goes through the download & update process regardless. I'd like to be able to first 'see' if there's an update to get.

Anyone know how? I'm sure I'm missing the obvious...

Answer (score 14, accepted):

you could use this one liner to check version:

```
$ curl -sS  https://api.github.com/repos/wayneeseguin/rvm/git/refs/tags | awk -F": |\"" '$2=="ref"{sub(/.*\//,"",$5); print $5}' | sort -V | tail -n 1
1.15.8
```

or a pure ruby one liner:

```
$ ruby -ropen-uri -rjson -e 'open("https://api.github.com/repos/wayneeseguin/rvm/git/refs/tags"){|r| puts JSON.parse(r.read).map{|l| l["ref"].gsub(/.*\//,"").split(".").map(&:to_i)}.sort.last.join(".") }'
1.15.8
```

but the simplest thing to do is:

```
$ curl https://raw.github.com/wayneeseguin/rvm/stable/VERSION
1.15.8
```

Comment: This is very useful.  Now to conditionally update rvm, I do `if [[ "$(rvm --version 2> /dev/null | awk '$2 != ""{print $2}')" != "$(curl https://raw.github.com/wayneeseguin/rvm/stable/VERSION 2> /dev/null)" ]]; then rvm get stable; fi`

Answer (score 5):

Curl the rvm repository like this:

```
curl  https://raw.githubusercontent.com/rvm/rvm/master/VERSION
```

Answer (score 1):

Ok, magic :)
Place this into some .rb file :)

```
require 'open-uri'
require 'openssl'

regex = Regexp.new(/data-name="([0-9]+).([0-9]+).([0-9]+)"/)
f=open("https://github.com/wayneeseguin/rvm",:ssl_verify_mode => OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE)
v = []
f.each_line do |l|
  regex.match(l) {|m| v << {:full => m[0], :major => m[1].to_i, :minor => m[2].to_i, :inc => m[3].to_i} }
end
v.sort_by{|m| [m[:major],m[:minor],m[:inc]] }
v=v.first
puts "#{v[:major]}.#{v[:minor]}.#{v[:inc]}"
```

I have no idea why I just did that.

Comment: Nice, *I think!?!* Didn't realize it would be this complicated!?! **RVM** needs an `outdated` command...

Comment: Well, you asked for a way to find latest available RVM version, I wrote a script that parses Github project page for you ;) Aren't we godsent software developers who can create tools? With minimal changes you can use this script to get latest version for almost any other Github repository :)

Comment: @daekrist your script is complicated, you can do it easier https://gist.github.com/3546691

Answer (score 0):

I used:

```
$ rvm get head && rvm reload
```

It ran fast and seemed to do the job.  I had installed rvm the week before, rvm 1.15.5, and already there was a newer version, rvm 1.15.8.

This was recommended on:

The Ruby on Rails Tutorial by Michael Hartl
http://ruby.railstutorial.org/ruby-on-rails-tutorial-book#sec-install_ruby

Comment: `rvm get` still performs installation while @Meltemi wants to just check for update.

Comment: Takes 20 or 30 seconds for me.